# Are dualizable modules finitely generated?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, and assume that $A$ has a dualizing complex $R$. Let $D(-) := \operatorname{RHom}_A(-,R)$ be the associated dualizing functor, and let $M$ be an $A$-module.

If $M$ is finitely generated, then the canonical map $M \to D(D(M))$ is an isomorphism in the derived category. What about the converse?

That is, if a bounded complex $M$ has the property that the canonical map $M\to D(D(M))$ is an isomorphism in the derived category over $A$, must $M$ have finitely generated cohomology?

Comment: If $A=\mathbb Z$, then it has a dualizing complex which is just $\mathbb Z$ and the Specker phenomenon gives a counterexample, I guess?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: That would give a counterexample for the ordinary Hom, but not the derived Hom.